# Finding the difference in number of words in a sentence in python

Tags: python

Say I have 2 sentences,

```
Ref: Q R CODE SCANNER APP EXIT KARE 
Hyp: WORKOUTS SCANNER APP EXIT KARE
```

Here we can see that the `Ref` has 3 different words from the `Hyp`, since the `Q R Code` is not present in Hyp. If there is any built-in function in Python that will check this and output 3 as a result?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What about the order? Would `"SCANNER APP EXIT KARE"` and `"EXIT KARE SCANNER APP"` be considered the same or with difference of 4?

Comment: Also how do you want to consider the lines as different? Can the words be out of order but present in both? Must they be in the same order? Are `"WORKOUTS"` and `"WORK OUTS"` considered different? How about `"WORKOUT"` and `"Workout"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```py
ref = "Q R CODE SCANNER APP EXIT KARE"
hyp = "WORKOUTS SCANNER APP EXIT KARE"

ref_set = set(ref.split())
hyp_set = set(hyp.split())

print(len(ref_set - hyp_set))  # 3
```

Note that this ignores the order of words, as well as ignoring duplicate words.